# Good software to explore the sqlite db file in device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

Is there a good software to explore the application bundle of an iphone app installed in the device? I'm specifically looking to extract the sqlite file from the application bundle?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoneview is useful for this...

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Answer (score -1):

I use sqlite-manager add-on for firefox.  Whcih is very flexible for searching and add/delete/update operations.

https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/